# req.users undefined react express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

so im getting an undefined response when fetching my api and i really dont know why

this is the function calls in the component

```
const init = usersId => {
   
    
    getUser(usersId).then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
            setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
        } else {
            // populate the state
            setValues({
                ...values,
                username: data.username,
                email: data.email,
               
                formData: new FormData()
            });
            
        }
    });
};
```

this is the api call in react

```
export const getUser = usersId => {
    console.log('ok')
    console.log(usersId)
    
    return fetch(`${API}/users/${usersId}`, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
        
};
```

at this point im getting the user id correctly but when the fetch is running i get an error that i cant read property of undefined so, there is the express server endpoint

```
router.get('/users/:usersId',
        read_);
```

and here is the controller

```
userCtrl.read_ = (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.users)
    console.log('test')
    return res.json(req.users);
};
```

i really dont know what im doing wrong at this point

Comment: Why do you expect the request to have a field `users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want `req.user` you'll have to find user from id.
you can get id by `req.params.userId`
after getting userdata from database assign user object to `req.user`

like this: `req.user = user;`
then you can access `req.user`

Answer (score 1):

You can't get `req.user`, cos you're not sending `req.user`.

You are only sending `userId` and you can only get it via `req.params`

like this

```js
req.params.userId
```

What you want to do is use the `userId` to get the associated `user` from your DB